# Symbol interpretation in non-constant power law density

Tags: interpretation, definition, networks, power-law

I am reading Barabasi book on network science. I am struggling to interpret the density formula for a power-law degree distribution with low-degree saturation and high-degree cut-off (http://networksciencebook.com/chapter/4#advanced-c):

[image]

The denominator of the constant in the PDF shows $\sum_{k'=1}$; what is this term summing over? all possible degree values between $k=1$ and $k_{max}$ even if not in the present in the data?

A similar sum $\sum_{k'=1}^k$ is present in the CDF, so in this case, I guess it's referring to all "possible" (i.e. not considering the data) degrees from 1 to the current $k$, isn't it?

I need the exact interpretation to implement these formulas into an algorithm.